# 5 most popular Boom mics, Lapel mics and HDD based recorders?

Tags: boom, lapel, shotgun, production

The cost or anything does not matter, just want to know 5 best and most used of Boom mics, Lapel mics and HDD based recorders

Comment: Best and most used are very different things. It also depends on what you want to do - especially with microphones? Perhaps try expanding your question a bit.

Comment: Hey Mark, you have a valid point. I need the info for a college project. I just need to know good and solid mics available out there. So lets say one good mic for recording bird sounds in a forest, one good mic for recording a car crash sound etc? Just some examples. Perhaps you can share something from what you've used r come across? Thanks :) 